# Is it possible to fit full coverage fenders on a road bicycle with V-brakes?

Tags: road-bike, fenders

I would like to get a used road bike on a budget. However, I need to ideally fit full coverage fenders due to frequent rain.

Do I simply need to save up for a bicycle with disc brakes, or should I look for a particular type of fork, frame, gap between the wheel and fork, that would allow the fitment of full coverage fenders?

I'm trying to avoid making this an opinion based question -- surely this must be a well-known problem with an equally well-known solution? It seems like most road bicycles have V-brakes, hence many would experience this exact problem?

Comment: You don’t mean v brakes for most road bikes

Comment: I have used the "clip-on" style mudguards on an old road bike used for daily, all-year commuting. They are designed to fit most road bike frames and don't require any specific mounting points. They definitely offer better spray protection than "mountain bike" style fenders, and almost as much as full-length ones.

Comment: If they're actually v brakes, then yes. A big advantage of V brakes is the room for mudguards. But I share @swifty's doubts: v brakes are common on hybrids and were common on mountain bikes, but have never been common on road bikes. I'm not even sure whether you'd get road bike levers to operate them.

Comment: @Swifty It depends what he means by "road bike."  And he is talking a used bike; my old Trek 520 had V-brakes.  (I don't know what the new ones have.)

Comment: @DavidW "Road bike" means what most non-experts would probably call a "racing bike". I've never seen one with V-brakes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Most of my co-workers refer to my touring bikes as "road bikes;"  the critical determinant seems to be drop bars.  And a few different lines of touring bikes had V-brakes for several years before they started using disc brakes.

Comment: @DavidW Really? I've never heard of a drop-bar brake lever that's compatible with V-brakes.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The Trek 520 did: https://archive.trekbikes.com/us/en/2005/trek/520#/us/en/2005/trek/520/details

Comment: I expect "road bike"  in this context just means a bike ridden on the road, and is detracting from the point so editing to remove. - Edit reverted waiting for clarity

Comment: I’m not convinced yet what the question is. I’d say v brakes are the easiest rim brake to fit a mudguard around - I thought it was a selling point. It would be helpful if AlphaCentauri you could illustrate the question with some pictures for what you mean by road bike and V brake, and maybe mention if there’s a cultural difference where you are to the meaning of road bike.

Comment: @DavidW 105, DuraAce, Ultegra, Deore, SRAM in a single drivetrain/shifting group. That's what I would call a real hybrid bike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing you need to look for is sufficient space around the tyre, at the chainstay and at the seatstay, as well as at the brakes.

It is also helpful if there are threadded holes down in the front and rear dropouts for mounting the mudguard/fender's stays.  Full-length fenders need a bit more support than stubby ones.

Most mudguard/fenders expect to mount to the brake bridge too, so your bike should have a through hole in the crown of the front fork, and  through the brake bridge over the rear wheel even if its got V brakes.  Most frames have this, but do check.

You can also bodge much of the mudguard functionality using a rear parcel rack.

V brake arms are normally long enough to clear the guards.  However mini-V brakes may not be long enough.

Comment: I've had that issue with mini-V brakes before. I ended up running the cable _underneath_ the mudguard, and cutting away the sides of the mudguard at that point

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you clarified what you mean by "road bike", since I've never seen a road bike with V-brakes. "Road bikes" are what many people would call "racing bikes" and they come with either disc brakes or caliper rim brakes; bikes with V-brakes tend to be either mountain bikes or hybrid/city bikes.

Nonetheless, it's perfectly possible to fit full fenders to a caliper-braked (or disc-braked) road bike, and also to a bike with V-brakes. Many road bikes don't come with the mounting bolt-holes for fenders but you can still fit fenders using other types of mount (e.g., clips or zip-tie-like straps around the forks).

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely *possible* to put fenders on a bike with V-brakes; my old Trek 520 had V-brakes and the fenders fit just fine.  (It was a bit tricky *attaching* the fenders, since I had to take the rack off to get access to the fender braze-ons, but once the fender was on it was fine.)

Depending on the geometry of your bike there are other clearances that may be more of a problem than the brake clearance, TBH.  (Some road bikes are really tight for space between the seat tube and the rear tire, for instance.)

For reference, this is the [2005 Trek 520](https://archive.trekbikes.com/us/en/2005/trek/520#/us/en/2005/trek/520/details) you can see there's plenty of space above the tire below the brake cable (more space in fact than between the tire and the rack):

[image: 2005 Trek 520]

The picture isn't very clear, but it came with [Avid SD5 brakes](https://www.rei.com/product/710542/avid-sd-5-v-brake):

[image: Avid SD-5 brakes]